# Program that returns input \t as *

Tags: java

The code is supposed to read an unidentified number of inputs from the keyboard and return any tabs as *. My program seems to work when I run it in eclipse and get no errors. When I turn in the code on the submission website, this is the error I get.

Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException: No line found  at java.util.Scanner.nextLine(Scanner.java:1589)    at replaceHW.main(replaceHW.java:9)

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class replaceHW {
public static void main(String[] args) {
//write a program that converts all TABS in your code
//with STARS i.e. *
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    String ans;
    while(!(ans = in.nextLine()).equals(""))
        System.out.println(ans.replace("\t","*"));
    }
}
```

Comment: @Carcigenicate yes the inputs are lines, I even tried in.next() and got a similar error

Comment: Could you describe how you execute your code outside Eclipse ?

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is simple: `nextLine()` works in tandem with `hasNextLine()`: the correct code is:

```
try (Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in)) {
  while (in.hasNextLine()) {
    String line = in.nextLine();
    if (!"".equals(line)) {
        System.out.println(ans.replace("\t","*"));
    }
  }
```

- The *try-with-resources* is best practice. But be wary than with System.in, it will close it when done.
- `hasNextLine()` will try to read has much input is needed to find a line.